# Linq based filtering for the class based on the list values

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
var filteredStudent = new List<Student>();
string description = "Managing the Course";
foreach (var student in students)
{
    if (student.subjetcs.Any(x => x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical")))
    {
        if (student.subjetcs.Any(x => x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical") &&
                                      description.Contains(x.Description)))
        {
           filteredStudent.Add(student);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        filteredStudent.Add(student);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to replace all the above logic with single Linq statement?

As I am interested in the Linq a lot

Comment: Yes, it's possible but you need to specify better the result you are looking for

Comment: Yes, it's possible. First simplify your logic to a single `if`, and then convert the loop to LINQ `Where` + `ToList`.

Comment: Yes, but it would look rather busy. It would also add extra iteration.

Answer (score 2):

First step: Simplify your logic.  And first step there, get rid of the redundant check for `Name.Contains("Critical")`.  By the time you've reached there, you are absolutely certain that Name contains "Critical".

So the criteria is -- IF the Name does NOT contain "Critical" OR (i.e., if it does) if the descriptions match.  And, if you think about it, that means the bit in the parentheses ("i.e, if...") become irrelevant.  If the descriptions match    then we always add the student whether or not it contains "Critical". And we also add the one without "Critical"  That can be rendered as:

UPDATED: octavioccl pointed out an error.

```
var filteredStudent = students
                  .Where(s=>!s.subjects.Any(x => x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical") || 
                            description.Contains(x.Description)))
                  .ToList();
```

NOTE: Given the update to the above, the second half would probably be faster than the first half, so we probably should reverse them.

```
var filteredStudent = students
                  .Where(s=>s.subjects
                    .Any(x => 
                        description.Contains(x.Description) ||
                        !x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical"))) 
                  .ToList();
```

UPDATED (Again)
Having thought about that overnight, I realized that doesn't work.  So, let's try this again....
 - We want all students EXCEPT those which have a subject containing "Critical", UNLESS that class's description matches.
(important note -- despite there being a Linq method called `Except()` that's not what we want -- we actually want **Where Not**.
SO, first stab at this is:

```
var filteredStudent = students
              .Where(s=>!s.subjects.Any(x => 
                          x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical")
                          ?  !description.Contains(x.Description)
                          : false)
              .ToList();
```

So, here the inner-most lambda (`x =>`...) is a test if a particular subject is a reason to reject the student. If it does not contain "Critical", it's OK (via the `false` at the end).  If it does, then it's rejected if the descriptions don't match.

However, from here we can shorten it.  Consider what we just said, if the first test is false, then whole thing is false. If the first test is true, then the whole express is true or false based on th esecond test --- which is exactly the definition of "short-curcuited AND" hence:

```
var filteredStudent = students
              .Where(s=>!s.subjects.Any(x => 
                          x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical")
                          &&  !description.Contains(x.Description))
              .ToList();
```

Read that we get, "We take all students except those who are taking any subject whose Sylabus Name contains "Critical" but does not have a matching description.

Comment: this will not produce the same result

Comment: @Fredou Why do you say that?  What condition would give a different result?

Comment: i think the double if on the same thing got me, after looking at it again it make sense

Comment: @Fredou Did you miss the "!" in the first part?

Comment: @JamesCurran, `subjects` is a collection according to OP

Comment: @octavioccl You're right.  A bit of oversimplication.  It's been fixed.

Comment: @James I don't think the order of `AND` / `OR` operators really matters in SQL. Actually the `x.Sylabus.Name` condition is eligible for using index (if exists).

Answer (score 1):

The condition for adding to the list of results is as follows:

> `Sylabus.Name` does not contain "Critical", or `Sylabus.Name` contains "Critical" and the `description` contains `Description`.

This can be coded into a single `Where` condition.

Comment: @JamesCurran You are right, I removed the suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you repeat the condition: `student.subjects.Any(x => x.Syllabus.Name.Contains("Critical"))`, and then use the same result: `filteredStudent.Add(student)`?

If you want to add all items in list, do something like this:

```
    students.ToList().ForEach(s => filteredStudent.Add(s));
```

If you want to filter the result, add `Where`:

```
    students.Where(s => s.subjetcs.Any(x => x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical") && description.Contains(x.Description)))
      .ToList().ForEach(s => filteredStudent.Add(s));
```

Maybe you want something like this:

```
    var list = new List<Stundent>();
    list.AddRange(studnets.Where(s => s.subjetcs.Any(x => x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical") && description.Contains(x.Description)));
    list.AddRange(studnets.Where(s => s.subjetcs.All(x => !x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical")));
    list.ForEach(x => filteredStudent.Add(x));
```

OR:

```
    students.Where(s => s.subjetcs.Any(x => x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical") && description.Contains(x.Description)) || s.subjetcs.All(x => !x.Sylabus.Name.Contains("Critical"))
      .ToList().ForEach(s => filteredStudent.Add(s));
```